# Conditional gradient for bar graph in Vega Lite

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I have some trouble changing colors based on value for gradient bars in Vega lite.

I am using the following lines that seem to work for changing the general color for the bars but not colors for the gradient:

```
"color": {
          "condition": [{"test": "datum['b'] < 0", "value": "red"}],
          "value": "green"
        }
```

This is the complete code, I have commented the section that works and the one that does not work (gradient):

[Code in Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0MTEDo-QAYXPUfgBmJ+uQFYARB4BOAEY3lYAUQeO3+h3exwAYg8xK9wSsAOIPfi-b4A44ACRBAHZ0egAJIwrZ7AC6BxAyHUAGs0KBMABPHBwY4mdRjeqNNnTEBRX5oX5Kel81ACnlbfmC8WoAAMShqBRocFkmGOw1MY1ybDwi1AbAAZnriiqZUoOU1aSB6rJyjo5DqQHlcsdlBMGAgFgByJgekmGAA8hmlY1mnhZgiQUBppKUIeZ6GsITyID2b31hrgxtFZq5oCtNt09sdxvGmDdnu9voAfIHg+5Q-HE8zoyBY2GI1HSSmlEr6uVZGQLVELXrFYJlMcUEoGUzjrJEsl3GNorELQkkno9e5ilOaJGIGhN4JtyBw0w4IJ9P3BHHZSekGfBAAFAp9geoAAsXZA9OHo-H6A2KdGTjEAAEcGECHRJmcZklGXfduRqUJbgac1uTzCo7W5ItnVdBBKFjQwAF4SJrGM6xAphw0jZNyLmY4AGJlGY5Mv2zC0MNtPQlgdNRixdUt3S9H1-TIlsKOOdQ4HHZtW3QGo4CVVi9iAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with negative values. We can hide the axis domain line, and instead use a conditional grid color to draw a zero baseline.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": -28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": -33},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": -19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "color": {
      "x1": 1,
      "y1": 1,
      "x2": 1,
      "y2": 0,
      "gradient": "linear",
      "stops": [
        {
          "offset": 0,
          "color": {
            "condition": [{"test": "datum['b'] < 0", "value": "black"}],
            "value": "white"
          }
        },
        {"offset": 1,
         "color": {
            "condition": [{"test": "datum['b'] > 0", "value": "white"}],
            "value": "black"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {
        "domain": false,
        "ticks": false,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelPadding": 4
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "gridColor": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.value === 0", "value": "black"},
          "value": "#ddd"
        }
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "condition": [{"test": "datum['b'] < 0", "value": "red"}],
      "value": "green"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to make the gradient display the same way for positive and negative values (0 = black to 10 = white and 0 = black to -10 = white).

Kind of the opposite of how it is shown in the following image

[image]

Comment: I would like to stick with Vega lite if possible, I am working with an application that is already using Vega lite. What I am trying to do is to make the gradient display the same way for positive and negative values (0 = black to 10 = white and 0 = black to -10 = white). I have updated the original question with additional information.

Comment: Which application are you working with?

Comment: It is an application I am helping build at work, I am modifying some parts including Vega lite components. I have not built the parts I am modifying but I thought it looked a little odd with the gradients not facing away from zero for both negative and positive values :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with negative values. We can hide the axis domain line, and instead use a conditional grid color to draw a zero baseline.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": -28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": -33},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": -19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
     "transform": [{"filter": "datum.b > 0"}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {
              "offset": 0,
              "color": "black"
            },
            {
              "offset": 1,
              "color":  "white"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "a",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "labelPadding": 4
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "b",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "gridColor": {
              "condition": {"test": "datum.value === 0", "value": "black"},
              "value": "#ddd"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
      {
     "transform": [{"filter": "datum.b < 0"}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {
              "offset": 0,
              "color": "white"
            },
            {
              "offset": 1,
              "color":  "black"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "a",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "labelPadding": 4
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "b",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "gridColor": {
              "condition": {"test": "datum.value === 0", "value": "black"},
              "value": "#ddd"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!